# Open a subfolder in Outlook and open the most recent email?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

This is what I have so far, I am having error with `"**._**"`  `folder("Delete Transactions")`.

```
Sub OpenDeleteTransactions()

   Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace

   Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

   Set Items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

   Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)._

   Folders("Delete Transactions").Items

   Set Items = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items

End Sub
```

The above is not working....

Answer (score 0):

Sort the items collection and retrieve the first (or last, depending on how you sort it) item:

```
Items.Sort("ReceivedTime", true)
set LatestMessage = Items.GetFirst()
MsgBox LatestMessage.Subject
```

Comment: hi thanks I will add that but the above given vba script is not working in my Outlook VBA. I am having error in "._ folder" please tell assist me with correct script to choose my subfolder named "Delete Trasactions"

Comment: Where is the folder located relative to other folders? What is the exact error?

Comment: is the `_` being used as the line continuation character? If it is the line actually is being interperted as `Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox). Folders("Delete Transactions").Items` which wont work because of the space before `Folders`. If it is not I doubt there is a Property or method `_` whcich returns items. [Here is MSDN on the Line Continuation Character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa711641(v=VS.71).aspx)